# Add element to DOM via directive and bind scope watching from controller (angular.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, 2-way-object-databinding

Here is the little app in which you can add items, edit them and delete - all described in controller, based on angular 2 way data-bind.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/schedule-of-the-red-hood

Everytime the element is added, in the calednar-bar programmatically should be inserted an element, described in directive's template:

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="event in events" class="event">' +
                    '<h3 ng-model="event.Name">{{event.Name}}</h3>' +
                    '<span ng-model="event.StartTime; event.EndTime" class="time">{{event.StartTime}}-{{event.EndTime}}</span>' +
                  '</div>'
```

Though I can't get it how to link the scope from controller, bind the element insertion from the controller:

```
$scope.addEvent = function(event, attrs) {
        $scope.events.push(event);
        $scope.event = {};  
        var eventGrid = angular.element(document.createElement('eventGrid')),
            el = $compile(eventGrid)($scope);            
        angular.element(document.body).append(eventGrid);
        $scope.insertHere = el;
      }
```

- as I understand now, my code creates an element in the DOM, but doesn't use template from directive... How can I do it? Is the chosen structure of code appropriate to this goal?

Comment: Please consider rewording, or posting some code.  I have re-read this about 10 times and still dont understand your issues.  I think you need to stop worrying about the "dom" and find a more data way to drive your templates.

Comment: thank you, Nix. updated. the problem is that i need to create two diff views of the same thing: user adds the item via inputs and the app should programmatically add the element to the calendar. this element should share the same scope as inputs and list-items and the data in them should stay always binded.

Comment: I honestly think things will work fine without the angular.element().append().  You just need to solve the "String" time issue.  I personally use MomentJS a lot, and it works well.

Comment: found one interesting solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667613/in-angular-how-to-pass-json-object-array-into-directive

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more data driven, forget about adding things to the dom.  E.g.

```
$scope.addEvent = function(event, attrs) {
    $scope.events.push(event);
    $scope.event = {};  
    /*var eventGrid = angular.element(document.createElement('eventGrid')),
        el = $compile(eventGrid)($scope);            
    angular.element(document.body).append(eventGrid);
    $scope.insertHere = el;*/
}


//add an order by to your ng-repeat
<li ng-repeat="event in events|orderBy:StartTime">
```

Instead of Saving `StartTime` as a string save it as a number, and use a filter to convert from seconds to your friendly `HH:MM:AM|PM.`

The conversion from string to seconds is the hardest part, but it is the right way to do it.