# Loading json data with an AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, factory

I have a huge json object in my controller that I would like to outsorce to a seperate file. So far I'm doing this:

```
myApp.controller('smController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...
  var stadtmobilRates = {
    classic: {
      A: {
        night: 0,
        hour: 1.4,
        day: 21,
        week: 125,
        km000: 0.2,
        km101: 0.18,
        km701: 0.18
      },
      ...
    }
  };
```

I have used a factory and promises as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668820/1257145) on Stackoverflow:

```js
myApp.factory('stadtMobilRates', function($http) {
  var promise = null;

  return function() {
    if (promise) {
      // If we've already asked for this data once,
      // return the promise that already exists.
      return promise;
    } else {
      promise = $http.get('stadtmobilRates.json');
      return promise;
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('smController', ['$scope', function($scope, stadtMobilRates) {
  var stadtmobilRates = null;
  stadtMobilRates().success(function(data) {
    stadtmobilRates = data;
  });
```

Now I'm getting a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` at the `stadtMobilRates().success(function(data) {` line. Why is the `stadtMobilRates` factory not accepted although I've injected it into the controller?

Edit #1: I've added the name of the factory to the array as suggested by prawn.

```js
myApp.controller('smController', ['$scope', 'stadtMobilRates', function($scope, stadtMobilRates) {
  var stadtmobilRates = null;
  stadtMobilRates().success(function(data) {
    stadtmobilRates = data;
  });

  console.log(stadtmobilRates);
```

However stadtmobilRates is `null`?

Edit #2: I've created a simplified version of my app on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tzZffSUYqLC6XyMxKJq?p=info). Well it works. On the full app I'm working with different routes, where `stadtmobilRates` still remains `null`. I'm unable to create a Plunker of the full app with the routes. So here is the full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/funkybaboon/c2g). The code above is from [Line 159](https://github.com/funkybaboon/c2g/blob/master/static/app.js#L159). I guess it has something to do with my routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to pass the name of the factory in the array. Typically you pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings followed by the function itself. Be sure to keep the array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration. This way the injector knows what services to inject into the function.

```
myApp.controller('smController', ['$scope', 'stadtMobilRates', function($scope, stadtMobilRates) {
```

**EDIT**

This is how I would do it...When routes are used I like to use `resolve` so the data gets loaded once and is stored. So in the `$routeProvider`, I would change the the smController part to the following...

```
 when('/sm', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/sm.html',
      controller: 'smController',
      resolve:{
              load:function(stadtMobilRates){
                  return stadtMobilRates.LoadData();
          }
    }).
```

I've also modified the factory

```
myApp.factory('stadtMobilRates', function ($q, $http) {
var mobilRates = null;

function LoadData() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('stadtmobilRates.json').success(function (data) {
        mobilRates = data;
        defer.resolve();
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

return {
    GetData: function () { return mobilRates ; },
    LoadData:LoadData
}
});
```

So before this route is loaded, it's going to call the `LoadData` function in the factory. Once the data gets loaded, it resolves the promise so this `LoadData` function will only get called once. Once the promise resolves, it will go ahead and load the view.

So now in your controller, whenever you want to get the data, all you have to do is call the function `GetData`

```
myApp.controller('smController', ['$scope', 'stadtMobilRates', function($scope, stadtMobilRates) 
{
     var stadtmobilRates = stadtMobilRates.GetData();
});
```

Comment: Is the data even set when you log it? Try putting the `console.log(stadtmobilRates);` inside the success function, not after it.

Comment: You are programming async. Put your console.log inside the callback.

Comment: Is in your project URL to json file in $http request correct?

Comment: It works on a simplified question of my app, however not with routes. I've updated the question.

Comment: updated my answer. let me know if it is at all helpful

Comment: Your solution works and I'll go with that. Still wondering why it was not working with the routes.