# AngularJS: Loading data only once and keep it persistent over all routes

Tags: json, angularjs

In this Question [Loading json data with an AngularJS factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714025/loading-json-data-with-an-angularjs-factory) prawn writes that the JSON file is only loaded once, but I made a test and it gets loaded again when I come back to that route.

What am I doing wrong here or did I misunderstand something?

Here´s my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k5DbhU6vdxP1Y6phhyzh?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl:'home.html', 
        controller:"MainCtrl",
        resolve: {
            load:function(userService){
                  return userService.loadData();
                }
        }
    })
    .otherwise( { 
        templateUrl:'other.html'
    })

});


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, userService) {
  var userData = userService.getData();

  $scope.name = userData.name;

});


app.factory('userService', function ($q, $http) {
var _data = null;

  function _loadData() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $http.get('user.json').success(function (data) {
          _data = data;
          console.log("user.json loaded");
          defer.resolve();
      });
      return defer.promise;
  }

  return {
      getData: function () { return _data ; },
      loadData:_loadData
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In userService you'll need to add some logic which checks if an $http request has already been made. Resolve will call userService.loadData() each time the state is visited, not once per page load.

```
var defer = false;

function _loadData() {
    if(!defer) {
        defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('user.json').success(function (data) {
            _data = data;
            console.log("user.json loaded");
            defer.resolve(data);
        });
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```