# Passing object to Angular directive attributes not coming through

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm passing through a JavaScript object to an Angular.js directive.  When logging `attrs` in the `link` function, I see my attribute there, but when logging `attrs.myOptions` there is no data:

```
var directive = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myOptions: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope)
      console.log(attrs)
      console.log(attrs.myOptions)
    }
  }
}
```

And i'm implementing it in my template like so:

```
<directive my-options="myObject" />
```

`myObject` is a JavaScript object that's set in the controller for the template.

And I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'myObject' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{myObject}}] starting at [myObject}}].
```

Comment: try accessing the object via `scope.myOptions` in the directive link function

Comment: try encapsulte it with `{}` like this `my-options="{myObject}"`

Comment: @paul147 when I log `scope`, I see `myOptions`, but when I log `scope.myOptions`, I get `undefined`. :(

Comment: And when I log `attrs` I see `myOptions` but the value is `myObject`..

Comment: What are the exact contents of myObject in the controller? This `[myObject}}]` looks like a template error but I'm not clear on how you managed to get there.

Comment: It's just an object with 5 keys and String values

Comment: @Noah take a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/oLCoGZ9CwuYMahx8lHpw?p=preview `attrs` is different from `scope`, attrs will always evaluate the value as a string while you can pass variables in as objects with scope.

Comment: Why is `scope.myOptions` undefined?

Comment: This answer did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667613/in-angular-how-to-pass-json-object-array-into-directive

Answer (score 4):

As suggested above you can use like this. only change that you have to access model though scope.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 

myApp.directive("directive",function() {
  return {
 restrict: 'E',
 replace: true,
 scope: {
   myOptions: '='
 },
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log(scope)
   console.log(attrs)
   console.log(scope.myOptions)
 }
  }
});
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObject = [1,2,3,4,5];
 console.log("app controller");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>   

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
 <directive my-options="myObject" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```